# What is the $GCD(2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1, 2^8+1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

My question is: 
$GCD(\frac{2^{40}+1}{2^8+1}, 2^8+1)$, but I'm stuck here: 
$GCD(2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1, 2^8+1)$. How I resolve this?

For to get $GCD(2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1, 2^8+1)$ I make the result that
$(x^5+y^5) = (x+y)(x^4 - x^3y + x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)$ and then, I choose $x = 2^8  $ and $y = 1$.

Comment: By the dupe the gcd $\,(f(x),x+1) = (f(-1),x+1),\,$ so specializing $\,f(x) = x^4\!-\!x^3\!+\!x^2\!-\!x\!+\!1,\ x = 2^8\Rightarrow $ your gcd $= (4,x+1)=1,\,$ by $x+1$ odd. $\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

$$2^8 \equiv -1 \pmod{2^8+1}$$

Therefore
$$2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1 \equiv (-1)^4-(-1)^3+(-1)^2-(-1)+1  \pmod{2^8+1}$$

Answer (score 5):

$x=2^8$ then $2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1=x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1$

Now, let's switch from numbers to polynomials $$x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 = (x+1)Q(x)+5$$
Where $Q(x)$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients and you can easily see the equality by substituting $x=-1$

From this and Euclidean algorithm:
$$ \text{gcd}(\frac{2^{40}+1}{2^8+1}, 2^8+1) = \text{gcd}(5, 2^8+1) = 1$$

Comment: Good. Of course $2^8+1=257$, which is either well known to be prime, or verifiably prime with a few moments’ thought, so relatively prime to $5$.

Comment: *Mathematica* yields $1$ instantly.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{array}{rrrrrrrrrrr}
      &  &        & 2^{24} &-2\cdot2^{16}       &+3\cdot 2^8 &-4 \\
      &  &---     &---     &---                 &---  &---\\
2^8+1 &| &2^{32}  &-2^{24} &+2^{16}             &-2^8 &+1 \\
      &  &2^{32}  &+2^{24} \\
      &  &---     &---\\
      &  &        &-2\cdot2^{24} &       +2^{16} \\
      &  &        &-2\cdot2^{24} &-2\cdot 2^{16} \\
      &  &        &---           &---\\
      &  &        &              &3\cdot 2^{16} &       -2^8 \\
      &  &        &              &3\cdot 2^{16} &+3\cdot 2^8 \\
      &  &        &              &---           &---\\
      &  &        &              &              &-4\cdot 2^8 & +1\\
      &  &        &              &              &-4\cdot 2^8 & -4\\
      &  &        &              &              &---         &---\\
      &  &        &              &              &            & +5
\end{array}

\begin{align}
   \gcd(2^{32}-2^{24}+2^{16}-2^8+1,2^8+1)
   &= \gcd(2^8+1, 5) \\
   &= \gcd(257, 5) \\
   &= 1
\end{align}